# Beginner question on dice roll statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, ordinal-data, multinomial-distribution

I have 2 cohorts of 10,000 people. I give each person in cohort 1 a die $a$, and ask them to roll it. I record the values as a tally. I then repeat this process with cohort 2 and give them die $b$.

I now have a table that looks like this:

cohort 1: 1=500, 2=1500, 3=5000, 4=2000, 5=1000

cohort 2: 1=100, 2=1000, 3=5000, 4=2500, 5=1400

I want to try and work out whether these results are statistically different. More specifically I want to understand if one die is more likely to produce a higher number.

While I can think of methods that do a lot of multiple comparisons such as $\chi^2$ tests I can't help think there must be a much better way to do this.

Comment: Could you also work with the question whether one die rolls a higher average? (Note that this is not equivalent to "one die is more likely to produce a higher number.")

Comment: what's the specific intent of the part about 'a higher number'?   A higher mean? Or something more literal, like p(B>A)$\neq$p(A>B)?

Comment: A higher number means is the die more likely to throw a 4, 5 or 6 than the other die. I don't want to look at just the mean. What I really want to be able to say is there is an increase in high number rolls which has come at the expense of low number rolls. If this was drawn as a curve I want to say that it has skewed to the right. For full disclosure I am not actually looking at dice rolling, it was just the best way to describe this

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Next question: are you *specifically* interested in the set {4,5,6}? Or would you be just as interested in just {6}, or {5,6}?

Comment: (Incidentally, your dice don't show a 6... Perhaps you want to edit your post to include the 6?)

Comment: oh yes, forget the 6 its not important. However, I can add this in if it helps? I am interested in whether 4 and 5 have increased and whether 1 and 2 have decreased

Comment: Does a change in 1 and 5 matter more than the same change in 2 and 4?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

Comment: @Glen_b no I don't think so

Comment: You are interested in a shift to higher numbers when going to B, rather than a shift in either direction?

Comment: Sorry Glen, I would be interested in either direction so it would need to be a 2 sided test

Comment: What if A had an excess of 4 and B had the same excess in 5 ... is that a difference you want to pick up?

Comment: Based on your example, if you throw both dice together, B has a significantly higher chance than 0.5 of yielding a higher roll than A. Is this a formulation that would work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with the chi-squared test? Just look at the $t = \sum \frac{(E-O)^2}{E}$ on $df = (5-1)(2-1)$.

Doing the calculations

```
countA = c(500,1500,5000,2000,1000)
countB = c(100,1000,5000,2500,1400)
t = sum((countA-countB)^2/countA)
1-pchisq(t,df = 4)
```

Doing this you get a p-value <<<< 0.05 So you know that the 2 are different. From here if you want to find the one most likely to give a higher number (over many throws) look for the one with the highest expect value.

```
resA = c(rep(1,500), rep(2,1500), rep(3,5000), rep(4,2000), rep(5,1000))
resB = c(rep(1,100), rep(2,1000), rep(3,5000), rep(4,2500), rep(5,1400))
mean(resA)
[1] 3.15
mean(resB)
[1] 3.41
```

So knowing they are statistically different and knowing that die b has a higher average you can say that die b is more likely to give a higher number over repeated trials.

You could also use the frequencies to calculate the probabilities of one dice throwing higher than the other.

$$P(B>A) = \sum_{N=2}^5(B=N~and~ A<(N-1))$$
Since the throws are independent 
$$P(B>A) = \sum_{N=2}^5[P(B=N) P(A<(N-1))]$$
$$P(B>A) = \sum_{N=2}^5[P(B=N) \sum_{n=1}^NP(A=n)]$$

Here we get $P(B>A) = 0.406$ and $P(A>B) = 0.2645$ Here we can see that dice B has a higher chance of having a larger roll than A.

Comment: This does not carry out the desired test, which concerns a *directional effect* among an *ordered set* of outcomes.  It can err by identifying a "significant" difference where neither die has a tendency to exceed the other on average.

Comment: @whuber what do you mean an ordered set of outcomes? The question is asked based off of counts from dice throws. I am a little confused by your comment

Comment: The outcome "5" on a die is considered greater than a "4", and so on: that is the ordering.  The question asks whether "one die is more likely to produce a higher" outcome.  That is the *alternative* hypothesis.  The $\chi^2$ test is inferior to other common tests for evaluating such hypotheses because it incorporates no information about the ordering and only detects differences in distribution. Although you can try to patch it up with some *post-hoc* testing, that is problematic because (a) you need to adjust the p-value and (b) you still likely wind up with an inferior test.

Comment: Ok I see that now from the comments. However I still think the wording of the question "I want to try and work out whether these results are statistically different. More specifically I want to understand if one die is more likely to produce a higher number." to be a little vague and could be easily understood as I did.

Comment: yes, sorry. I can see that its a bit confusing. I will try and edit

Answer (score 1):

Suppose one die $X$ can produce the values $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \cdots \lt x_m$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_m$ (respectively) and the other die $Y$ can produce values $y_1\lt y_2 \lt \cdots \lt y_n$ with probabilities $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_n$ (respectively).  Consider a game in which $X$ and $Y$ are independently tossed.  For independent throws, the chance $X$ exceeds $Y$ is

$$\Pr(X\gt Y) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j\mid x_i \gt y_j}^n p_iq_j.$$

From your (many) observations you can *estimate* the chances $p_i$ and $q_j$ and thereby estimate this probability.

**To assess the uncertainty in the probability estimate, consider bootstrapping the data.**  One bootstrap iteration consists of constructing dice $X^{*}$ and $Y^{*}$ having the observed probabilities and rolling the pair ten thousand times--that is, for as many times as you have observations--and tallying the frequencies of the events $X^{*} \gt Y^{*},$ $X^{*} \lt Y^{*},$ or $X^{*}=Y^{*}.$  After several bootstrap iterations--50 may do, 500 is good, and an efficient algorithm with a modern computer will permit many more--you can study the distributions of these frequencies.  They reveal the likely uncertainties in the inferences you will be drawing from your data.

**Allow me to illustrate with a smaller dataset having more uncertainty.**  I have divided your counts by 100, producing two sets of 100 observations.  Here are the results of 10,000 bootstrap iterations:

[image: Figure]

For example, the lefthand plot headed "$P(x \gt y)$" shows the two bootstrapped dice tended to tie about 26% of the time, but the rates of ties varied from 15% to 40%.  Proceeding to the right, we see $X^{*}$ was less than $Y^{*}$ about 41% of the time ($X^{*}$ "lost" and $Y^{*}$ "won"), but this frequency varied from 25% to 55%; and $X^{*}$ won about 33% of the time, varying from 25% to 44%.  Finally, at the far right is a histogram of the difference in winning frequencies.  This difference averaged about -0.15 but extended from -0.4 to +0.1 within the bootstrap.  The vertical red line is the threshold of zero: only 3% of all the results are positive.  Put another way, in only 3% of the bootstrap iterations did $X^{*}$ win more often than $Y^{*}.$

The 3% number is a bootstrap "p-value" for testing whether $X$ has a lower rate of winning than $Y.$  As such, it is "one sided."  At the outset you likely wanted to test only whether $X$ and $Y$ have *different* winning rates.  That p-value for that "two sided" test is obtained by doubling the one-sided p-value to 6%.

The two-sided bootstrap p-value of 6% is small enough to give some evidence that $X$ will tend to win less often than $Y.$  It often would not be considered "significant" evidence where only values of 5% or less are considered sufficient evidence.

**With the large amount data you actually have, the results are clear:** on average $X^{*}$ wins 26.5% of the time, $Y^{*}$ wins 40.5% of the time, (and the remaining times they tie).  The p-value is less than $10^{-4},$ which is so tiny we may infer with high confidence that $Y$ wins more often than $X:$ about 14% more often.  (Notice the nature of this inference: from observed behaviors of $X^{*}$ and $Y^{*}$ we are making deductions about $X$ and $Y.$  That's the essential idea of the bootstrap.)  In this particular bootstrap calculation (again with 10,000 iterations) the difference in winning frequencies ranges from -17% to -11%, reflecting some remaining uncertainty about how much inferior $X$ is to $Y:$ but inferior it is.

Finally, note that the right hand histogram provides information not afforded by, say, a chi-squared test: its quantitative display of *plausible alternative estimates* shows you the amount of *risk* you undertake when making an inference about winning rates from your data.

---

The following `R` code performed the bootstrapping and (after first dividing `x` and `y` by 100) created the figure.

```
x <- c(500, 1500, 5000, 2000, 1000); names(x) <- 1:5
y <- c(100, 1000, 5000, 2500, 1400); names(y) <- 1:5
#
# Compute chances of winning, losing, and tieing given two dice.
#
p <- function(x, y) {
  p <- outer(x, y) / (sum(x) * sum(y))
  x.gt.y <- outer(as.numeric(names(x)), as.numeric(names(y)), `>`)
  x.lt.y <- outer(as.numeric(names(x)), as.numeric(names(y)), `<`)
  x.eq.y <- ! (x.gt.y | x.lt.y)
  c(`P(x > y)`=sum(p[x.gt.y]), `P(x < y)`=sum(p[x.lt.y]), `P(x==y)`=sum(p[x.eq.y]))
}
#
# Bootstrap the data.
#
n <- 1e4
x.boot <- rmultinom(n, sum(x), x) # This summarizes n * sum(x) = 10^8 throws of `X`
y.boot <- rmultinom(n, sum(y), y) # This summarizes n * sum(y) = 10^8 throws of `Y`
bootstrap <- sapply(seq.int(n), function(i) p(x.boot[,i], y.boot[,i])) # Compare the dice
bootstrap <- rbind(bootstrap, 
                   `P(x>y)-P(x<y)`=bootstrap["P(x > y)", ] - bootstrap["P(x < y)", ])
#
# Plot the results.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
sapply(rownames(bootstrap), function(s) hist(bootstrap[s,], main=s, xlab="Value"))
abline(v=0, col="Red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#
# Compute and report a one-sided p-value.
#
(p.value <- mean(bootstrap["P(x>y)-P(x<y)",] > 0))
```